# How do I generate array values in Vue.js and show them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I only just started learning vue, trying to practice

```js
export default {
    name:'FrontPage',
    data: function(){
        return {
            player: [
                { 'ap': ngen() },
                { 'df': ngen() },
                { 'iq': ngen() },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ngen: function() {
            return Math.random()
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h2> {{ player.ap }} </h2>
        <h2> {{ player.df }} </h2>
        <h2> {{ player.iq }} </h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question lacks a description of how your current approach fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dynamic array value display :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 v-for="player in players" v-bind:key="player.prop2">{{ player.prop1 }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FrontPage",
  data: function() {
    return {
      players: [{ prop1:this.ngen(), prop2:0}, 
                { prop1:this.ngen(), prop2:1},
                { prop1:this.ngen(), prop2:2}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ngen: function() {
      return Math.random();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basing on what you want to get as results, I think it's not necessary to have the player array in your data object.

Just define your random method and call it in your template.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h2> {{ ngen() }} </h2>
        <h2> {{ ngen() }} </h2>
        <h2> {{ ngen() }} </h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

or just do a call of the JavaScript random function directly

Answer (score 1):

first you should call ngen  with `this.ngen()`

also your players are in array

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ player[0].ap }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ player[1].df }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ player[2].iq }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

see live example

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sunset-yphur

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
export default {
    name:'FrontPage',
    data: function(){
        return {
            player: {
                'ap': this.ngen(),
                'df': this.ngen(),
                'iq': this.ngen(),
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ngen: function() {
            return Math.random()
        }
    }
}

<template>
    <div>
        <h2> {{ player.ap }} </h2>
        <h2> {{ player.df }} </h2>
        <h2> {{ player.iq }} </h2>
    </div>
</template>
```